# Alternatives to nested ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

Suppose we have the following data. The rows represent a country and the columns (`in05:in09`) indicate whether that country was present in a database of interest in the given year (`2005:2009`).

```
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
in05 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
in06 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1)
in07 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
in08 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1)
in09 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, in05, in06, in07, in08, in09)
```

I want to create a variable `firstyear` which indicates the first year in which the country was present in the database. Right now I do the following:

```
df$firstyear <- ifelse(df$in05==1,2005,
    ifelse(df$in06==1,2006,
        ifelse(df$in07==1, 2007,
            ifelse(df$in08==1, 2008,
                ifelse(df$in09==1, 2009,
                    0)))))
```

The above code is already not very nice, and my dataset contains many more years. Is there an alternative, using `*apply` functions, loops or something else, to create this `firstyear` variable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can vectorize using `max.col`

```
indx <- names(df)[max.col(df[-1], ties.method = "first") + 1L]
df$firstyear <- as.numeric(sub("in", "20", indx))
df
#   id in05 in06 in07 in08 in09 firstyear
# 1  a    1    0    1    0    0      2005
# 2  b    0    0    1    1    0      2007
# 3  c    0    0    0    1    0      2008
# 4  d    1    1    1    1    1      2005
```

Comment: Good old `max.col` - always comes to the rescue. Though it's really quite annoying that it defaults to `"random"` for dealing with ties, considering `which.max` / `which.min` etc always take the first result they hit.

Answer (score 21):

```
df$FirstYear <- gsub('in', '20', names(df))[apply(df, 1, match, x=1)]
df
  id in05 in06 in07 in08 in09 FirstYear
1  a    1    0    1    0    0      2005
2  b    0    0    1    1    0      2007
3  c    0    0    0    1    0      2008
4  d    1    1    1    1    1      2005
```

There are many ways to do it. I used `match` because it will find the first instance of a specified value. The other parts of the code are for presentation. First going line by line with `apply` and naming the years by the column names with `names`. The assignment `<-` and `df$FirstYear` is a way to add the result to the data frame.

added credit @David Arenburg has a cool idea about subbing the `in` for `20` in the `FirstYear` column.

Comment: I thought that was a clever trick, too.. @akrun would be proud

Answer (score 8):

Another answer with some notes of efficiency (although this QA is not about speed).

Firstly, it could be better to avoid the conversion of a "list"-y structure to a "matrix"; sometimes it's worth to convert to a "matrix" and use a function that handles efficiently a 'vector with a "dim" attribute' (i.e. a "matrix"/"array") - other times it's not. Both `max.col` and `apply` convert to a "matrix".

Secondly, in situations like these, where we do not need to check all the data while getting to a solution, we could benefit from a solution with a loop that controls what goes through to the next iteration. Here we know that we can stop when we've found the first "1". Both `max.col` (and `which.max`) have to loop once to, actually, find the maximum value; the fact that we know that "max == 1" is not taken advantage of.

Thirdly, `match` is potentially slower when we seek only one value in another vector of values because `match`'s setup is rather complicated and costly:

```
x = 5; set.seed(199); tab = sample(1e6)
identical(match(x, tab), which.max(x == tab))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(match(x, tab), which.max(x == tab), times = 25)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#       match(x, tab) 142.22327 142.50103 142.79737 143.19547 145.37669    25
# which.max(x == tab)  18.91427  18.93728  18.96225  19.58932  38.34253    25
```

To sum up, a way to work on the "list" structure of a "data.frame" and to stop computations when we find a "1", could be a loop like the following:

```
ff = function(x)
{
    x = as.list(x)
    ans = as.integer(x[[1]])
    for(i in 2:length(x)) {
        inds = ans == 0L
        if(!any(inds)) return(ans)
        ans[inds] = i * (x[[i]][inds] == 1)
    }
    return(ans)
}
```

And the solutions in the other answers (ignoring the extra steps for the output):

```
david = function(x) max.col(x, "first")
plafort = function(x) apply(x, 1, match, x = 1)

ff(df[-1])
#[1] 1 3 4 1
david(df[-1])
#[1] 1 3 4 1
plafort(df[-1])
#[1] 1 3 4 1
```

And some benchmarks:

```
set.seed(007)
DF = data.frame(id = seq_len(1e6),
                "colnames<-"(matrix(sample(0:1, 1e7, T, c(0.25, 0.75)), 1e6), 
                             paste("in", 11:20, sep = "")))
identical(ff(DF[-1]), david(DF[-1]))
#[1] TRUE
identical(ff(DF[-1]), plafort(DF[-1]))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff(DF[-1]), david(DF[-1]), as.matrix(DF[-1]), times = 30)
#Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#        ff(DF[-1])  64.83577  65.45432  67.87486  70.32073  86.72838    30
#     david(DF[-1]) 112.74108 115.12361 120.16118 132.04803 145.45819    30
# as.matrix(DF[-1])  20.87947  22.01819  27.52460  32.60509  45.84561    30

system.time(plafort(DF[-1]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.117   0.000   4.125
```

Not really an apocalypse, but worth to see that simple, straightforward algorithmic approaches can -indeed- prove to be equally good or even better depending on the problem. Obviously, (most) other times looping in R can be laborious.

Comment: Brilliant. As always... Long time ago I was writing very efficient loops on lists and my code was blazing fast, but SO ruined me with the "anti-loop" philosophy  :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Looping is a way of life - you can hide it, 'vectorize' it but you can't avoid it.. :-)

Comment: nice answer; you might be interested in the commentary in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `dplyr::case_when` inside `dplyr::mutate()` along the lines of the method presented in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/nj_tierney/status/811367917627404288).

```
# Using version 0.5.0.
# Dev version may work without `with()`.    
df %>%
      mutate(., firstyear = with(., case_when(
        in05 == 1 ~ 2005,
        in06 == 1 ~ 2006,
        in07 == 1 ~ 2007,
        in08 == 1 ~ 2008,
        in09 == 1 ~ 2009,
        TRUE ~ 0
)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option:

```
years <- as.integer(substr(names(df[-1]), 3, 4)) + 2000L
cbind(df, yr=do.call(pmin.int, Map(`/`, years, df[-1])))
```

Produces:

```
  id in05 in06 in07 in08 in09   yr
1  a    1    0    1    0    0 2005
2  b    0    0    1    1    0 2007
3  c    0    0    0    1    0 2008
4  d    1    1    1    1    1 2005
```

And is fast.  Here timing only the finding the min year step using Alexis' data:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                       expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 do.call(pmin.int, Map(`/`, 11:20, DF[-1])) 178.46993 194.3760 219.8898 229.1597 307.1120    10
                                 ff(DF[-1]) 416.07297 434.0792 439.1970 452.8345 496.2048    10
                   max.col(DF[-1], "first")  99.71936 138.2285 175.2334 207.6365 239.6519    10
```

Oddly this doesn't reproduce Alexis' timings, showing David's as the fastest.  This is on R 3.1.2.

---

**EDIT**: based on convo with Frank, I updated Alexis function to be more compatible with R 3.1.2:

```
ff2 = function(x) {
  ans = as.integer(x[[1]])
  for(i in 2:length(x)) {
      inds = which(ans == 0L)
      if(!length(inds)) return(ans)
      ans[inds] = i * (x[[i]][inds] == 1)
  }
  return(ans)
}
```

And this comes closer to the original results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
  ff(DF[-1]) 407.92699 415.11716 421.18274 428.02092 462.2474    10
 ff2(DF[-1])  64.20484  72.74729  79.85748  81.29153 148.6439    10
```

Comment: Interesting. Maybe an R version thing. When I run `microbenchmark(do.call(pmin.int, Map(\`/\`, 11:20, DF[-1])),ff(DF[-1]),max.col(DF[-1], "first"),times=10)` on R 3.2.0 with Alexis' example data I get Alexis 150, Brodie 275, David 430 (for the mean or median).

Comment: @Frank Hmm, I guess I'll check this gain when I upgrade, though the truly mystifying thing is that `max.col` gets _slower_.

Comment: @Frank, I have a theory as to why `Alexis` is faster.  I think R 3.2.0 is smarter about `x[logical]` vs `x[which(logical)]`.  The latter is traditionally much faster.  On my system `x <- logical(1e5); x[sample(1e5, 1e4)] <- TRUE; microbenchmark(x[which(x)], x[x])` is 8x faster for the `which` version.  Can you run that on yours?

Comment: Yeah, on mine I have multiple versions of R. 3.2.0 -- 2x as fast for `which`; 3.0.1 -- 3-4x

Comment: On R-3.2.0, I get `ff: 100 ms | ff2: 65 ms`; on R-3.1.2, `ff: 230 ms | ff2: 75ms`. I'm not able to get my initial 65 ms for ff. For the `x[logical]` VS `x[which(logical)]`, `x[which(x)]` is 3 ms on both versions of R, but `x[x]` is 5 ms on R-3.2.0 VS 12 ms on R-3.1.2. Looking at [R-3.1.2's `logicalSubscript`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-3-1-2/src/main/subscript.c)  VS [R-3.2.0's `logicalSubscript`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-3-2-0/src/main/subscript.c), it seems that R-3.2.0 avoids extended use of "%" in returning integer indices from the logical ones (to be -subsequently- used).

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer to work with tidied data. First method filters on cumsums

```
# Tidy
df <- df %>% 
  gather(year, present.or.not, -id) 

# Create df of first instances
first.df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id, present.or.not) %>% 
  mutate(ranky = rank(cumsum(present.or.not)), 
         first.year = year) %>% 
  filter(ranky == 1)

# Prepare for join
first.df <- first.df[,c('id', 'first.year')]

# Join with original
df <- left_join(df,first.df)

# Spread
spread(df, year, present.or.not)
```

Or this alternative that, after tidying, slices the first row from arranged groups.

```
df %>% 
  gather(year, present_or_not, -id) %>% 
  filter(present_or_not==1) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(year = str_replace(year, "in", "20")) %>% 
  select(1:2) %>% 
  right_join(df)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Other messy alternatives:

```
library(tidyr)
library(sqldf)
    newdf <- gather(df, year, code, -id)
    df$firstyear <- sqldf('SELECT min(rowid) rowid, id, year as firstyear
                            FROM newdf 
                            WHERE code = 1
                            GROUP BY id')[3]
```

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df, year, code, -id)
df2 <- df2[df2$code == 1, 1:2]
df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2$id), ]
merge(df, df2)
```

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
    newdf <- gather(df, year, code, -id)
    df$firstyear <- (newdf %>% 
                      filter(code==1) %>%
                      select(id, year) %>%
                      group_by(id) %>%
                      summarise(first = first(year)))[2]
```

Output:

```
  id in05 in06 in07 in08 in09 year
1  a    1    0    1    0    0 in05
2  b    0    0    1    1    0 in07
3  c    0    0    0    1    0 in08
4  d    1    1    1    1    1 in05
```

A **cleaner solution** combining plaforts solution with alexises_laz is:

```
names(df) <- c("id", 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009)
df$firstyear <- names(df[-1])[apply(df[-1], 1, which.max)] 

  id 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 firstyear
1  a    1    0    1    0    0      2005
2  b    0    0    1    1    0      2007
3  c    0    0    0    1    0      2008
4  d    1    1    1    1    1      2005
```

If we'd like to keep the original column names we could use the renaming provided by @David Arenburg.

```
df$firstYear <- gsub('in', '20', names(df[-1]))[apply(df[-1], 1, which.max)]

  id in05 in06 in07 in08 in09 firstYear
1  a    1    0    1    0    0      2005
2  b    0    0    1    1    0      2007
3  c    0    0    0    1    0      2008
4  d    1    1    1    1    1      2005
```