# Converting Factor into numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a column for Months. They are written in words and stored as factor. I want to get corresponding numeric values for them and I tried the following code but it is not working

```
Latest<-MasterFile
for(i in 1:nrow(MasterFile)){
  if(MasterFile[i,2]=="Januray"){
    MasterFile[i,2]=1
  }
    else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="February"){
      MasterFile[i,2]=2
    }
      else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="March"){
        MasterFile[i,2]=3
      }
        else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="April"){
          MasterFile[i,2]=4
        }
          else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="May"){
            MasterFile[i,2]=5
          }
             else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="June"){
               MasterFile[i,2]=6
             }
               else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="July"){
                 MasterFile[i,2]=7
               }
                  else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="August"){
                   MasterFile[i,2]=8
                  }
                     else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="September"){
                       MasterFile[i,2]=9
                     }
                        else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="October"){
                          MasterFile[i,2]=10
                        }
                          else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="November"){
                           MasterFile[i,2]=11
                          }
                            else if(MasterFile[i,2]=="December"){
                              MasterFile[i,2]=12
                             }
}
```

Comment: what is `levels(MasterFile[,2,drop = TRUE]` ? if levels appear then perform `as.numeric` on it

Answer (score 3):

Probably the month levels are in alpha order. Refactor them in the correct order before converting to numeric:

```
as.numeric(factor(MasterFile[, 2], levels = month.name))
```

This uses the built-in variable `month.name` to order the levels of the factor correctly in month order, at which point `as.numeric` converts the levels to their corresponding level numbers.

Some further reading that might help you: [Vectorized if statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042413/903061), (you should at least be using `ifelse()` rather than `for() {if() else}`), but there are often better approaches: [Alternatives to nested `ifelse` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30494520/903061)

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use `match` with `month.name` as the second argument.

```
match(MasterFile[, 2], month.name)
```

This will return a vector of the length of the number of rows in MasterFile with the positions the the values there lie in the built-in constant `month.name`.