# Vectorized 'if' statement without 'ifelse'

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I have figured out a very inefficient way of using vectors in an `if` statement, but can't figure out how to use `ifelse()` or `sapply()` or any better way of doing it.

I have the following data:

```
yes_codes <- c(1,3,7)
yes_year <- 2011
df2 <- data.frame(yes_codes, yes_flags, yes_year)
codes <- c(1:10)
flag <- 'N'
year <- c(2011,2012,2011,2012,2011,2013,2014,2015,2011,2010)
df <- data.frame(codes, flag, year)

> df
   codes flag year
1      1    N 2011
2      2    N 2012
3      3    N 2011
4      4    N 2012
5      5    N 2011
6      6    N 2013
7      7    N 2014
8      8    N 2015
9      9    N 2011
10    10    N 2010
> df2
  yes_codes yes_flags yes_year
1         1         Y     2011
2         3         Y     2011
3         7         Y     2011
```

I need to match the `df$code` with `df$yes_codes` and set the `df$flag` to 'Y' when they match.  The only way I have figured out how to do this is very very obviously wrong

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for(z in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if(df$year[i]==2011 | df$year[i]==2012)
      if(as.character(df$code)==as.character(df2$yes_code[z]))
        if(df$year[i]==df2$yes_year[z])
          df$flag[i] <- 'Y'
  }
}
```

I know you're supposed to use `ifelse()` to do vectorized `if` statements, but this doesn't work either

```
ifelse(df$year==2011 | df$year==2012, ifelse(df$code==df2$yes_code, 
ifelse(df$year==df2$year, df$flag <- 'Y',
            df$flag <- 'N'), df$flag <- 'N'), df$flag <- 'N')
```

This sets EVERY flag to 'Y' or 'N' with every iteration and all I get is whatever was set last, which is usually 'N'.  I really thought I had found a perfect example of why you use `<-` and `=` for different things, but it won't even run when I switch the `<-` for `=`.

**EDIT:**
As Sotos explained to me, `ifelse()` simply returns a function so I need to set my values outside of it.  My problem now is that I actually have several `ifelse()` conditions that I need to check because for example I have one rule that applies to 2011 and 2012 and another that applies to 2012 and greater. Writing multiple `ifelse()` statements just overwrites the output of the previous one with the `else` output when done as follows:

```
df$flag <- ifelse(df$year==2013 & df$codes==df2$yes_code & df$year==df2$yes_year, 'Y', 'N')
df$flag <- ifelse(df$year >= 2012 & df$codes=='4', 'Y', 'N')
df$flag <- ifelse((df$year==2011 | df$year==2012) & df$code==df2$yes_code & df$year==df2$year, 'Y', 'N')
```

It's having to use `else` that is making this so difficult, is there any other way to use a vectorized `if` statement?

Comment: Your `ifelse` statement is wrong. One problem is that you can not use `<-` inside `ifelse`... You can do `df$flag <- ifelse...`

Comment: Thanks!  That was what I needed to get moving.  I've updated my question with another wall I'm hitting though.

Comment: You can also nest `ifelse` statements, `ifelse(condition1, result1, ifelse(condition2, result2, result3))`. You might want to read [alternatives to nested `ifelse` statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30494520/903061). But at some point, if you have multiple rules applying to the same line you have to choose which one happens last (you say you have a rule for 2011 and 2012, and another rule for 2012 and greater, which means both these rules apply to 2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the info I got in this thread, the answer to my first problem was 'don't try to set values inside of an `ifelse()`, use `ifelse()` to return a value and set it that way.

The second problem I was having with the `else` portion of my statement overwriting previous statements, the answer was maddeningly simple: just return the current value.  So the following

```
df$flag <- ifelse((df$year==2011 | df$year==2012) & df$code==df2$yes_code &
df$year==df2$year, 'Y', 'N')
```

becomes this

```
df$flag <- ifelse((df$year==2011 | df$year==2012) & df$code==df2$yes_code &
df$year==df2$year, 'Y', df$flag)
```

Thanks to all who helped, this was a very difficult question to articulate.

Comment: Is your code working with `df$code==df2$yes_code`? From your question: `df` and `df2` have different number of rows.

Comment: @jogo yea it seems to be working, I used an rpivottable to verify that rules had been applied like I was expecting and it seems to have worked.  I don't think the number of rows matching was important.

Would it be better to use` %in%` or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
df3<-merge(df, df2, by.x='codes', by.y='yes_codes',all.x = TRUE)
df3$flag<-ifelse(df3$yes_flags=="Y", "Y", "N")
df3$flag[is.na(df3$flag)]<-"N"
df<-df3[,!(names(df3) %in% names(df2))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I thought about using merge() instead too but I need to be able to apply rules from multiple ifelse() statements. The example I provided may have been too simplified.

Comment: Sure. You can stack if ifelse statements so they don't write over values:       val0<-ifelse(cond, "val1",NA)                                                                          val0<-ifelse(newcond, "val2",val0)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt2 <- data.table(yes_codes=c(1,3,7), yes_flags='Y',yes_year=2011)
dt  <- data.table(codes=(1:10), flag='N', year=c(2011,2012,2011,2012,2011,2013,2014,2015,2011,2010))

dt[dt2, on=c(codes="yes_codes", year="yes_year"), in.df2:=i.yes_flags]

dt[year==2013 & in.df2=='Y', flag:='Y']
dt[year>=2012 & codes==4, flag:='Y']
dt[(year==2011 | year==2012) & in.df2=='Y', flag:='Y']
dt
#    codes flag year in.df2
# 1:     1    Y 2011      Y
# 2:     2    N 2012     NA
# 3:     3    Y 2011      Y
# 4:     4    Y 2012     NA
# 5:     5    N 2011     NA
# 6:     6    N 2013     NA
# 7:     7    N 2014     NA
# 8:     8    N 2015     NA
# 9:     9    N 2011     NA
# 10:    10    N 2010     NA
```

or you can do it in one big condition:

```
dt[(year==2013 & in.df2=='Y') | (year>=2012 & codes==4) | 
               ((year==2011 | year==2012) & in.df2=='Y'), flag:='Y']
```

you can put the first and the third condition together:

```
dt[((year==2011 | year==2012 | year==2013) & in.df2=='Y') | (year>=2012 & codes==4), flag:='Y']
# and shorten it:
dt[((year %in% 2011:2013) & in.df2=='Y') | (year>=2012 & codes==4), flag:='Y']
```