# prevent condition has length > 1 with := operator in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I create a `data.table` like this:

```
dd<-data.table(c(7,8,9),c(10,5,10),c(8,9,11))
```

I then try to pass it a function using `:=` but I get condition has length > 1 error.

```
dd[,Cat:= as.factor(if(V1 > V2 & V2 > V3) 
{"decrease,decrease"} else if(V1 > V2 & V2 < V3)
{"decrease,increase"} else if(V1 < V2 & V2 < V3)
{"increase,increase"} else if(V1 < V2 & V2 > V3)
{"increase,decrease"})]
```

I know this is because this is how `if` works. I could do something like the following if I only had two columns:

```
dd[, Cat:= as.factor(ifelse(V1>V2, "increase", "decrease"))]
```

Which works because `ifelse` is apparently vectorized. But I have three different outputs I would like to produce, not two.

Comment: You could also work on subsets in stead. e.g., `dd[V1 > V2 & V2 > V3, Cat := {"decrease,decrease"}]` in order to avoid `if` statements/nesting all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `ifelse`,

```
ifelse(V1 > V2 & V2 > V3, "decrease,decrease",
    ifelse(V1 > V2 & V2 < V3, "decrease,increase",
        ifelse(...)))
```

But in this case I would probably do `paste(ifelse(V1 < V2, "increase", "decrease"), ifelse(V2 < V3, "increase", "decrease"), sep = ",")` so I didn't have to write out every combination.

See alse [Alternatives to nested ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30494520/903061) and [nested ifelse statement in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18012222/903061).